How to open files that are " mimetypeapplication/epub+zip"
I downloaded a book that created a folder with many files that looked like this:
08/14/2024  11:44 AM         6,409,791 fdd113aab580c34ae2386a797154587a
08/13/2024  06:55 PM        11,513,824 fddd50d655b083abf29cda955967c7a9
08/13/2024  06:48 PM        25,541,101 fe3db8f782d896180bae1e829b514e9e
08/14/2024  09:28 AM         8,581,351 fe3dbdccbc4637ddf7cd1aeedc9875e0
08/14/2024  09:28 AM         4,066,371 fe3f25076c640ef4d34bdd4a96febf28
08/13/2024  06:46 PM         9,411,020 fea03a549e4c5ed4fb49486db2ba5da2
I opened one of the files in notepad++ and it was all encrypted except for this part:
"mimetypeapplication/epub+zip"
How do I view the content of these files?
TIA
-X
